# Exclude User IDs which have ineracted which specific values

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to exclude User IDs based if the User have interacted with a specific campaign (in this case Campaign_ID 4).

```
User_ID | Campaign_ID| Value1| Value 2, Value 3, etc.
--------|------------------------------------       
|  1    | Campaign_1 | 1     |               |
|  1    | Campaign_4 | 1     |               |
|  2    | Campaign_1 | 1     |               |
|  3    | Campaign_1 | 1     |               | 
|  3    | Campaign_2 | 1     |               |
|  3    | Campaign_3 | 1     |               | 
|  4    | Campaign_1 | 1     |               |
|  4    | Campaign_4 | 1     |               |
|  5    | Campaign_3 | 1     |               |
---------------------------------------------
```

I have tried the following Query to exclude all User_IDs that have interacted with Campaign_ID 4 in some way:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM Report_1
WHERE Campaign_ID IN ("1", "2", "3")
  AND User_ID NOT IN (SELECT User_ID FROM Report_1 WHERE Campaign_ID IN ("4"))
```

However, the query only removes the rows where the campaign_ID is 4:

```
User_ID | Campaign_ID| Value1| Value 2, Value 3, etc.
--------|------------------------------------       
|  1    | Campaign_1 | 1     |               |
|  2    | Campaign_1 | 1     |               |
|  3    | Campaign_1 | 1     |               | 
|  3    | Campaign_2 | 1     |               |
|  3    | Campaign_3 | 1     |               | 
|  4    | Campaign_1 | 1     |               |
|  5    | Campaign_3 | 1     |               |
----------------------------------------------
```

What I would like to see is that all rows which contains User_IDs which have interacted with Campaign_ID 4 disappears (in this case User_ID 1 and 4).

```
User_ID | Campaign_ID| Value1| Value 2, Value 3, etc.
--------|------------------------------------       
|  2    | Campaign_1 | 1     |               |
|  3    | Campaign_1 | 1     |               | 
|  3    | Campaign_2 | 1     |               |
|  3    | Campaign_3 | 1     |               | 
|  5    | Campaign_3 | 1     |               |
---------------------------------------------
```

Is there any way to setup a query which do this?

Thanks!

@ EDIT: I have added a another column the table (the real table contains 30 different columns)

Comment: I have tried your SQL ([Fiddle](http://rextester.com/XUNR23366)), and it have return the result you expected.  Could you [edit] your question to better demonstrate your question?

Comment: None of your Campaign_ID's are 1, 2, 3 or 4. You're not supposed to get any rows at all with that query.

Comment: Your query is invalid standard SQL. Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using?

Comment: I am using BigQuery with the Standard SQL Dialect.

Answer (score 0):

If your compaign_id column has text has **Campaign_1** for compaign_id 1 and **Campaign_2** for compaign_id 2 etc. then below query will suffice your requirement

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM Report_1
WHERE User_ID NOT IN 
(SELECT User_ID FROM Report_1 WHERE Campaign_ID = 'Campaign_4');
```